# jQuery UI datepicker: Is there a way to display leading zeros in the dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need do display leading zeros in the jQuery UI datepicker:

**e.g.,**

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` -> `01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10`

Similar question to this one:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/displaying-leading-zero-for-day-numbers-of-datepicker

Maybe someone does have a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my hack solution. It works! :)

We can use combination of CSS and JavaScript. There is one `datepicker` event [`beforeShowDay`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) which we can exploit in our approach.

*CSS:*

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar td.zero a:before {
    content: "0";
}​
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$("input").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay : function(date) {
        var day = date.getDate();
        return [true, (day < 10 ? "zero" : "")];
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vZ7wm/

Comment: tested it with firefox and it's working - thanks. But it's not working with IE9. Is there a chance to get this thing work with the lovely IE?

Comment: @KeithL. Hm, my IE9 displays zeros perfectly. The only problem can cause CSS `:before` pseudo element which is [supported by IE starting from version 8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to hack daterpicker plugin.

Get `_generateHTML` method.
After

`for (var dow = 0; dow < 7; dow++) {` // create date picker days

place this code

```
var customgetDate = printDate.getDate();
if(customgetDate<=9){
 customgetDate= '0'+ customgetDate;
}
```

Then  find  this "  `printDate.getDate() + '</a>')`    "  now replace this with;

```
 customgetDate + '</a>')
```

Thats all.....

Answer (score 0):

To display leading zeros for month numbers?
Maybe something like this:

```
<script type="javascript/text">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cssselector").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

outdated accepted answer. should be:

```
$('#fromDate, #toDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yymmdd'
});
```